# работа с option

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый вечер.

Цель задачи: при нажатии ***`Кнопка 3`*** блокировать все `option в select` кроме строк ***`2 3 и 5`***.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.group')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var elem = e.target;
  if (elem.hasAttribute('data-select')) {
    let select = document.querySelector('#select');
    select.value = elem.getAttribute('data-select');

    let options = document.querySelectorAll('#select option');

    if (select.value == 4) {
      options.forEach(el => el.disabled = false);
    } else options.forEach(el => el.disabled = (el.value !== select.value ? true : false));
  }
  select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label class="primary">
        <input data-select="3" type="button">Кнопка 1</label>
  <label class="primary">
        <input data-select="4" type="button">Кнопка 2</label>
  <label class="primary">
        <input data-select="5" type="button">Кнопка 3</label>
</div>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Выбор пункта 1</option>
  <option value="2">Выбор пункта 2</option>
  <option value="3">Выбор пункта 3</option>
  <option value="4">Выбор пункта 4</option>
  <option value="5">Выбор пункта 5</option>
  <option value="6" checked>Выбор пункта 6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.group').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var elem = e.target;
  if (elem.dataset.select) {
    let select = document.querySelector('#select');
    select.value = elem.dataset.select;

    var options = select.querySelectorAll('option');
    options.forEach(el => {
      if (select.value == 5) { // здесь только логика для "Кнопка 3"
        el.disabled = el.value != 2 && el.value != 3 && el.value != 5;
      } else {
        // *** код из вопроса - администрация ответственности не несет
        if (select.value == 4) {
            options.forEach(el => el.disabled = false);
        }
        else options.forEach(el => el.disabled = (el.value !== select.value ? true : false));
        // ***
      }
    });
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label class="primary">
        <input data-select="3" type="button">Кнопка 1</label>
  <label class="primary">
        <input data-select="4" type="button">Кнопка 2</label>
  <label class="primary">
        <input data-select="5" type="button">Кнопка 3</label>
</div>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Выбор пункта 1</option>
  <option value="2">Выбор пункта 2</option>
  <option value="3">Выбор пункта 3</option>
  <option value="4">Выбор пункта 4</option>
  <option value="5">Выбор пункта 5</option>
  <option value="6" checked>Выбор пункта 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Igor , можно сделать код, чтоб "Кнопка 1" и "Кнопка 2" работали как в первом сообщении? Код не мой, писал не я поэтому реанимировать после вашего дополнения я не могу.

Comment: Igor большущее человеческое спасибо!